# urllib.request.urlopen not working for a specific website

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used urllib.request.Request for the url of a memidex.com page, but the urllib.request.urlopen(url) line goes on to fail to open the url.

```
url = urllib.request.Request("http://www.memidex.com/" + term)
my_request = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
info = BeautifulSoup(my_request, "html.parser")
```

I've tried using the same code for a different website and it worked for that one so I have no idea why it's not working for memidex.com.

Comment: What do you mean by _fail to give me my request_ ?

Comment: My_request is what I named the variable for the urllib.request.urlopen() line. Urllib.request.urlopen() is failing to open the url that I gave it in the previous line.

Comment: The program just hangs/freezes?

Comment: I have the program set up to print "Not found" when the website doesn't have what I'm looking for so since it can't open the url it just prints that.

Comment: There’s a difference between a request not having the content you need, and a request which fails entirely, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add headers to your url request in order to overcome the error. BTW 'HTTP Error 403: Forbidden' was your error right?
Hope the below code helps you.

```
import urllib.request

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
url = "http://www.memidex.com/"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 
request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
print(data)
```